# Updating counters through Hibernate

Tags: sql, mysql, hibernate, transactions, counter

This is an extremely common situation, so I'm expecting a good solution.  Basically we need to update counters in our tables.  As an example a web page visit:

```
Web_Page
--------
Id
Url
Visit_Count
```

So in hibernate, we might have this code:

```
webPage.setVisitCount(webPage.getVisitCount()+1);
```

The problem there is reads in mysql by default don't pay attention to transactions.  So a highly trafficked webpage will have inaccurate counts.

The way I'm used to doing this type of thing is simply call:

```
update Web_Page set Visit_Count=Visit_Count+1 where Id=12345;
```

I guess my question is, how do I do that in Hibernate?  And secondly, how can I do an update like this in Hibernate which is a bit more complex?

```
update Web_Page wp set wp.Visit_Count=(select stats.Visits from Statistics stats where stats.Web_Page_Id=wp.Id) + 1 where Id=12345;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem there is reads in mysql by default don't pay attention to transactions. So a highly trafficked webpage will have inaccurate counts.

Indeed. I would use a DML style operation here (see chapter [13.4. DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct)):

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

String hqlUpdate = "update webPage wp set wp.visitCount = wp.visitCount + 1 where wp.id = :id";
int updatedEntities = s.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
        .setLong( "newName", 1234l )
        .executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Which should result in

```
update Web_Page set Visit_Count=Visit_Count+1 where Id=12345;
```

> And secondly, how can I do an update like this in Hibernate which is a bit more complex?

Hmm... I'm tempted to say "you're screwed"... need to think more about this.

Comment: Thank you Pascal.  I didn't know I could do UPDATEs within HQL.  Looks easy.  But regarding my more complex example, would that fall victim to the same SELECT issue of not paying attention to transactions?  How do you suggest I handle that?

Answer (score 0):

A [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines-syntax.html) offers several benefits:

1. In case the schema changes, the code need not change if it were `call increment($id)`
2. Concurrency issues can be localized.
3. Faster execution in many cases.

A possible implementation is:

```
create procedure increment (IN id integer)
begin
    update web_page
      set visit_count = visit_count + 1
      where `id` = id;
end
```